# How to find all occurrences of the smallest 1st index of each tuple in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I need to find the minimum y value in a set of x-y points given as a list of tuples but I also need the returned point to be the one that has the maximum x value if there happens to be two occurrences of the minimum y value.
I was thinking if I could find all the points with the minimum y value and append them to a list I could then use something along the lines of:

```
max(listPts, key=itemgetter(0))
```

to then find the point that has the maximum x out of them.

an example input would be

```
[(188, 564),
 (478, 395), 
 (135, 309),
 (513, 309),
 (410, 398)]
```

and the output:

```
(513, 309)
```

Comment: `min(your_list_of_tuples, key=lambda t: (t[1], -t[0]))`, see the dupe.

Comment: Cheers for the reply